# ClassCastException : cannot be cast to class and are in unnamed module of loader 'app'

Tags: java, spring-boot, visual-studio-code, classcastexception

I am trying to build a simple email sending application in visual studio code.

The tutorial that I am following is this:

https://www.technicalkeeda.com/spring-boot-tutorials/how-to-send-email-using-spring-boot

When I run my project I am getting this exception error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class 
MailServiceImplementation cannot be cast to class 
MailService 
MailServiceImplementation and 
MailService are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
```

To see my `MailService` and `MailServiceImplementation` classes, please visit the above mentioned link. Kindly help me with this error.

Comment: Class name is MailServiceImpl and not MailServiceImplementation. Please check

Comment: @Naruto Is MailServiceImlp a pre-defined name or something? Can I not change it to anyother name? I have renamed this on my own. and have used the same everywhere in my code. I dont think it should make any differnence.